# How to change Nodejs 8.x version to Nodejs 6.x version?

Tags: node.js

I am learning JavaScript on Flatiron School. When I opened a lab on JavaScript section in the IDE it said:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module.   
Expected version "6.x". Got "8.15.0"
```

How to change my node.js version from `8.x` to `6.x`?

Comment: I got node.js 6.x version now. But it sitll said: 

`The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "6.x". Got "8.15.0"`

Comment: don't downgrade, 8.15.0 has async/await + oop. Or even better, use node.js 10.5+, it comes with multithreading

Comment: I can see your point, it is logical and reasonable. But I don't know when I opened a repo on Github and try to work with my local machine. I got `node.js 8.x version already` but the IDE from Flatiron School (the website teaches JS I've been following) displayed `my node` not compatible with this module `expected 6.x version got 8.15.0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please install nvm by clicking the following link
https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Using this nvm you can switch between different node versions

To install node version:

```
nvm install v6.11.5 32
```

Use:

```
nvm use 6.11.5 32
```

To check which version is selected:

```
nvm list
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should use [nvm](https://michael-kuehnel.de/node.js/2015/09/08/using-vm-to-switch-node-versions.html) to switch between node.js versions

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade use where version is the node version you require

```
npm install node@<version>
```